# WriteFile with an overlapped occasionally gives me ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. Am I doing memset correct?

Tags: c++, writefile

I am using WriteFile to write to a file and I am getting an error of ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE sometimes. I read that this could be because the value of HANDLE in Overlapped is invalid.
But I am just having a hard time figuring this out. I wonder if something is going out of scope. Would appreciate it if someone can take a look. I can always add more code here

```
const LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped = GetOverlapped(true, hFile, ulBufSize, &ullFileOffset,volumeName);
    if (lpOverlapped == nullptr)
    {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return false;
    }

    if (!WriteFile(hFile,(const PVOID)(((UINT64) s_pMemoryBuffer[volumeName]) + iBufferOffset),ulBufSize,&dwBytesWritten,lpOverlapped))
    {   
           DWORD errCode = GetLastError(); //Error here
           //Why do I get an error code 6 here every now and then
    }
```

Now this is the method that returns the overlapped structure

```
LPOVERLAPPED foo::GetOverlapped(bool useOverlappedIo, HANDLE hFile, UINT32 ulBufSize, UINT64* ullFileOffset,const std::string& volumeName)
{
    if (useOverlappedIo)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (index < cMaxOverlappedIOS)
            {
                if (!OverlappedInUse[volumeName][index])
                {
                    OverlappedInUse[volumeName][index] = true;
                    LPOVERLAPPED overlapped = &(OverlappedArray[volumeName][index]);

                    if (overlapped->hEvent == nullptr) // Need Event
                    {
                        overlapped->hEvent = CreateEvent(
                            nullptr,
                            TRUE,
                            TRUE,
                            nullptr);
                        if (overlapped->hEvent == nullptr)
                        {
                            printf("Error creating event (error code: %u)\n", GetLastError());
                            return nullptr;
                        }
                    }

                    overlapped->Offset = (UINT32)(*ullFileOffset & 0xFFFFFFFF); // Low order 32 bits
                    overlapped->OffsetHigh = (UINT32)(*ullFileOffset >> 32); // High order 32 bits
                    *ullFileOffset += ulBufSize; // Update pointer to next record
                    return overlapped;
                }
                // Else Keep looking
                index++;
            }
            // None available, wait for at least one to free up
            if (WaitForPendingIOs(hFile, FALSE,volumeName) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                return nullptr;
            }
        } // Now start loop over again
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

This is how I am initializing the array before this code gets called

```
for(auto vol : readVolumes)
{
    OVERLAPPED* oarray = new OVERLAPPED[cMaxOverlappedIOS];
    memset(oarray, 0, sizeof(oarray));
    OverlappedArray[vol] = oarray;

    bool* boolinuse = new bool[cMaxOverlappedIOS]{false};
    OverlappedInUse[vol] = boolinuse;

    s_pMemoryBuffer[vol] = nullptr;
    s_uDataBufferSize[vol] = 0;

}
```

Any suggestions on why I would get that error ?

Comment: @HansPassant I added how I am creating OverlappedArray  if that helps

Comment: or should it be like this `memset(oarray, 0, (size_t) cMaxOverlappedIOS * sizeof(OVERLAPPED))`